# NX Server - reinstallation does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nx-client, freenx, nx-server

I had a remote server that I used to connect via NX client from a Windows XP machine.

Suddenly it stopped working and the quick fix option for me was to restore the remote server from a previous image where everything was working. I did that, but now the previous user's setup is failing authentication (including root). I had the system passwords reset, yet NX client would fail authentication. Does anyone have a clue about this behavior?

To solve that problem, I am trying to reinstall NXserver on the remote Linux Ubuntu 11.X.X server.

I am not a Linux techie (to be specific, I am an ASP.Net Project Manager), so please bear with me.

I get the following error on installing the NXServer .deb file for amd64:

```
# sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.5.0-9_amd64.deb
Selecting previously deselected package nxserver.
(Reading database ... 138791 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nxserver (from nxserver_3.5.0-9_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nxserver:
 nxserver depends on nxclient (>= 3.5.0); however:
  Package nxclient is not installed.
 nxserver depends on nxnode (>= 3.5.0); however:
  Package nxnode is not installed.
dpkg: error processing nxserver (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nxserver
```

Should I be downloading and installing the NXClient and NXNode on this server?

I want to be sure, because I don't want to mess up this server and as I can't handle the command line world that I am forced into right now.

Comment: Well, went ahead and installed the client and the node as mentioned in the previous error message. Not the NXserver installation has something else to complain about an NX user already existing. See the error message below:

Comment: # sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.5.0-9_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 139244 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace nxserver 3.5.0-9 (using nxserver_3.5.0-9_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nxserver ...
Setting up nxserver (3.5.0-9) ...
NX> 704 ERROR: Cannot add user: nx.
NX> 704 ERROR: User: nx already exists.
NX> 704 To fix the problem, you may try to completely uninstall NX
NX> 704 Server and install it from scratch. If this is not enough,
NX> 704 please delete the nx user by using the system commands and
NX> 704 proceed with a new installation of NX Server.

Comment: dpkg: error processing nxserver (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nxserver

Comment: The console output is hard to read in a comment.  Please edit your question and paste the console output there, and use the `{}` button on the edit box toolbar to correctly format it as console output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you already figured out, you need to also install the nxnode and nxclient packages.  That's what the error messages from dpkg were telling you.

nx does seem to be being stupid about failing its installation just because the nx user already exists.  Try running `deluser nx`, and then running the installation again.

About the authentication failure you mentioned:  nx can be configured to use the system user/password database, or its own database.  Look for the `EnablePasswordDB` and `EnableUserDB` options in /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg, and read about those options in section 4 of the [NX server admin guide](http://www.nomachine.com/documents/admin-guide.php), and also [How does the NX login work?](http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR02C00150)  If NX is using its own user/password database, then you may have to reset that too.